# Run-time error '7': Out of memory

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word, runtime-error

I'm trying to edit embedded charts in Word documents. My source code is below. It has worked a long time but not for the last two days. I get this error:

> Run-time error '7':   Out of memory

I have searched a lot , but I don't understand the problem. When I shutdown computer and after open it, then it works correctly, but after I get error again.

It gives error in this part:

```
       'create range with Cell
        Set oChart = oInShapes.Chart
        oChart.ChartData.Activate  ' ***Note: It gives error here***
        'Set oWorkbook = oChart.ChartData.Workbook
        Set oWorksheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        Set oRange = oWorksheet.Range(Cell)
```

---

```
Public Sub updatechart(Doc As word.Application, ChartName As String, ChartTitle As String, Cell As String, data As String)`

        Dim oInShapes As word.InlineShape
        Dim oChart As word.Chart
        Dim oWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'Dim oWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

        Dim columnArray() As String
        Dim rowArray() As String
        Dim oRange As Range
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        For Each oInShapes In Doc.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        ' Check Shape type and Chart Title
            If oInShapes.HasChart Then
                'create range with Cell
                Set oChart = oInShapes.Chart
                oChart.ChartData.Activate  ' ***Note: It gives error here***
                'Set oWorkbook = oChart.ChartData.Workbook
                Set oWorksheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
                Set oRange = oWorksheet.Range(Cell)
                ' Commet for debug
                'oWorksheet.Range("B33") = (ChartTitle & 33)

                ' Split text
                columnArray = Split(data, SeperateChar)
                For i = LBound(columnArray) To UBound(columnArray)
                    rowArray = Split(Trim(columnArray(i)), " ")
                    ' Set Title. For example; ChartTitle = "XY" ----- Table Titles ---->  | XY1 | XY2 | XY2 | ....
                    ' After Set Value                                                     | 0,33| 0,1 | 0,46| ....
                    oRange.Cells(1, i + 1) = ChartTitle & (i + 1)
                    For j = LBound(rowArray) To UBound(rowArray)
                        ' Set Values
                        oRange.Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = CDbl(rowArray(j))
                    Next j
                Next i

                'oWorkbook.Close
                oChart.Refresh
            End If
        Next

        Set oInShapes = Nothing
        Set oChart = Nothing
        Set oWorksheet = Nothing
        'Set oWorkbook = Nothing
        Erase rowArray, columnArray
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question yet?

Comment: @GrahamAnderson Do you have same problem?

Comment: This error could occur due to an Excel formula string being too long (> 8,192 characters).

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before. I had the same solution, exit excel, free up some memory and try again - and it worked. You may have to shut down other programs while using this. Its literally what it says it is, lack of available memory.

Keep in mind that if you've run other macros that copy information to the clipboard, you will have less RAM freed up to run the macro.

Also, are you using 32 or 64 bit Excel - 64 will allow you to use more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you not set oRange to nothing when cleaning up your sub, could it be that this object is using a lot of memory which isn't being released when the sub ends?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and finally traced it down to the "For Each" statement. I think it has to do with the memory allocation for the Collection, Doc.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes in your example.

My bad code (PowerPoint to Excel):

```
For Each sh In InputBook.Sheets("Exec Sum").Shapes
    sh.Visible = False
Next
Set sh = Nothing
```

My fixed code:

```
For i = 1 To InputBook.Sheets("Exec Sum").Shapes.Count
    InputBook.Sheets("Exec Sum").Shapes(i).Visible = False
Next
```

Avoiding a reference to a collection solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The frequent access to the worksheet can create problems with resource usage. The way to go about this is to fetch data in a single access point, like

```
Dim V as Variant
V = InputRange
' Now V becomes a m x n array of the cell values in InputRange
' you may manipulate and work with this data and fill all your results in 
' OutputV(m,n) variant array

Dim OutputV() as Variant
ReDim OutputV(m,n)
oRange = OutputV
```

Usually speeds up the code by several hundred times depending on the size of the range and also uses far less resources.