# Insert pivot table from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying for hours now to create a pivot table from VBA. I've tried various codes but i keep getting errors. The following code does not create a pivot table it only creates a new sheet. I have a sheet called "Base" where all my data is. It has 18288 rows and 13 columns with data. Can anyone help me with why the code isn't working for me

```
Sub pivottable()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As pivottable
Dim PRange As range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Base")


LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")


Sheets("PivotTable").Select


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_LETTER"), "Sum of amount", xlSum



End Sub
```

Comment: Since you have tried multiple codes, it would be helpful if you at least summarized what you attempted, so that you won't get repeat recommendations. Since you have gotten errors, you should give more information on what those errors are; that information can be quite helpful. Since _something_ in your code isn't working, you should let us know which of the code lines is problematic, so that we have more of a starting point. It's easier to troubleshoot when we have the details. I'll try to check back later, after you've added details, and see if I can help. (Right now, I can't really tell....)

Comment: Try not to use `On Error Resume Next` - better to let the error occur and handle it, rather than ignore it. Remove it and you'll be able to tell exactly what line is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
Sub pivottable()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As pivottable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim new_sheet As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

new_sheet_name = "PivotTable"
pivot_table_name = "pivot_name_here"

Set new_sheet = Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet)

With new_sheet
.Name = new_sheet_name
End With

Set PSheet = new_sheet
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Base")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=PRange.Address(, , xlR1C1))

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
            (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1), TableName:=pivot_table_name)

With PTable.PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With PTable
    .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_LETTER"), "Sum of amount", xlSum
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a run time error 7 at:
  .Name = new_sheet_name

Comment: @ChrisTJ see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277514/run-time-error-7-out-of-memory

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this link is cold, but in case someone else wants to do this, here's code I adapted from other answers (StackOverflow and elsewhere) to create several Pivot Tables. This code receives a  Global Variable from above that is an array with 7 salesman's names. The code:

1. Finds the range of the data on each "salesman's" sheet.
2. Creates a Pivot Table **Cache** with the salesman's name (this was the key to getting it to work).
3. Creates a Pivot table with the salesman's name.
4. Labels and sorts the Pivot Table.
5. Moves on to the next Sheet.

---

```
  Sub Pivot_Maker() 'adapted from the internet. I added the arrays tho - AAI
  'as of 11/26/2019

  Dim FinalRow            As Long
  Dim DataSheet           As String
  Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
  Dim PvtTbl(7)              As PivotTable
  Dim DataRng             As Range
  Dim TableDest           As Range


  i = 0


  Do While i < NumSalesPeeps
      Sheets(Salesman(i)).Select

  Range("A1").Select


If IsEmpty(Range("A30")) Then GoTo No_Data

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    PvtTblName = ActiveSheet.Name & "pvt"

    ' set data range for Pivot Table
    Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 10))  ' conversion of R1C1:R & FinalRow & C8

    ' set range for Pivot table placement
    Set TableDest = Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(1, 12)  ' conversion of R1C9


    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, DataRng)

    ' this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PvtTbl(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables(PvtTblName) ' check if PvtTblName Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

    On Error GoTo 0
    If PvtTbl(i) Is Nothing Then ' PvtTblName doesn't exist >> create it

        ' create a new Pivot Table in PvtTblName sheet
    Set PvtTbl(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=TableDest, TableName:=PvtTblName)


    With PvtTbl(i).PivotFields("Account")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With PvtTbl(i).PivotFields("Name")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        PvtTbl(i).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            PvtTblName).PivotFields("Amount"), "Sum of Amount", xlSum

    Else
        ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
        PvtTbl(i).ChangePivotCache PvtCache
        PvtTbl(i).RefreshTable
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PvtTblName).PivotFields("Sum of Amount")
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    End With
  No_Data:

  i = i + 1
 Loop
 End Sub
```