# VBA Excel open closed file and copy specific columns then save to different file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file which is closed I need to process it by running the macro from another file.
Copy specific columns by ID or name then save them in a different file to disk.

I've tried adapting this code but I'm having issues trying to implement it from a different file, with the code I'm testing it copy the data in the same file which runs the code.

Also is it possible to add headers and a title to the first and second row to the newly created file?

```
Sub test()
Dim mywb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set mywb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim vFile
    Dim fn
    Dim x As Integer, t As Integer
    Dim v As Variant, vName As Variant
    
    ' Specify the colum numbers to be copied. column 1 is ID 1
    v = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  11, 12, 55, 67)
    
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files(*.csv),*.csv", , "please select a file", MultiSelect:=False)
    'vFile = "test.csv"
    If vFile = False Then Exit Sub
   '
    vName = Split(vFile, "\")
    vName = Replace(vName(UBound(v)), ".csv", "")
    'vName = "Sheet2"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set sh = mywb.Sheets.Add(before:=mywb.Sheets(1))
    sh.Name = vName
    
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFile, Local:=True
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'copying columns assigned in v array
    t = 1
    For x = 0 To UBound(v)
        wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x)).Copy sh.Cells(1, t)
        t = t + 1
    Next
    
    sh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    wb.Close False
    
    
    
    'Creating CSV file
    fn = vName & ".csv"
    
    sh.Copy
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "OUTPUT.CSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
    sh.Delete
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

end sub
```

Comment: "I'm having issues" - can you elaborate on those issues?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've edited the question adding "with the code I'm testing it copy the data in the same file which runs the code."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub test()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim vFile, arr, fn
    Dim x As Long
    Dim v As Variant, vName As Variant
    
    ' Specify the colum numbers to be copied. column 1 is ID 1
    v = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 55, 67)
    
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files(*.csv),*.csv", , "please select a file", MultiSelect:=False)
    If vFile = False Then Exit Sub
    arr = Split(vFile, "\")
    fn = arr(UBound(arr))
   
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=vFile, Local:=True
    Set wb = Workbooks(fn)
    Set sh = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(1)) 'add new sheet
    
    'copying columns assigned in v array to the new sheet
    For x = 0 To UBound(v)
        wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x)).Copy sh.Cells(1, x + 1)
        'sh.Columns(x+1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x)).Value 'copy values only
    Next
    sh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit 
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Sheets(1).Delete 'remove the original data
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    wb.SaveAs wb.Path & "\" & "OUTPUT.CSV"
    wb.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I'm getting "runtime error '7' out of memory in line wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x)).Copy sh.Cells(1, x + 1) when v(x) = "missing" and x = 12. column 12 exists in the spreadsheet. I've tried rebooting and closing all programs and executing again.  where should I look at? thanks for looking into this.

Comment: How can `v(x)` be "missing" ? - isn't `v` an array of column numbers?

Comment: I guess when I put the mouse over the sentence doesnt get evaluated, I am looking at a performance issue maybe, I've seen some users having the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277514/run-time-error-7-out-of-memory

Comment: How large is your data?  You could try assigning values directly instead of copy/paste (unless you need to preserve formatting/formulas)

Comment: there are some fields with a lot of text. how can assign the values directly?

Comment: Try the line I added.  How large are your files?

Answer (score 0):

Without you saying what issues you are having, it is hard to speak to how to prevent them.  At a guess, one thing that you might be running into is column height - Excel sometimes does weird stuff copying into certain versions from csv files when you try to copy the whole column.  If that rings a bell, just copy an intersection of the full column and the used range of the page rather than the full column.

With regard to adding headers and such - yeah, that's easy.  Near the end, where you've got this code (this won't work, btw, unless you switch over to the intersection as advised above, so you'll want to dim CopyRange as Range):

```
    For x = 0 To UBound(v)
        wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x)).Copy sh.Cells(1, t)
        t = t + 1
    Next
```

Just paste into the 3rd row instead and add your headers in:

```
For x = 0 To UBound(v)
        Set CopyRange = Intersect(wb.Sheets(1).Columns(v(x), wb.sheets(1).UsedRange)
        CopyRange.Copy sh.Cells(3, t)
        sh.Cells(1,t).value="Put a title here"
        sh.Cells(2,t).value="Put a header here"
        t = t + 1
Next
```

Obviously, you'll likely want those to vary, so rather than hardcoding the string, go with a variable or an array that you modify accordingly (an array of strings could work well, then you could just do TitleArray(t) and HeaderArray(t)).

Good luck!